# Selecting multiple values from select tag - Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, springsource

Could you please anyone tell me how to get multiple values from

```
<g:select multiple="multiple" ...
```

I have this in my create.gsp

```
<g:select name="validator.id"  multiple="multiple" optionKey="id" from="${com.project.Validator.list()}" value="${validators}" />
```

and this is in OperationLogContoller.groovy

```
def create = {
    def operationLogInstance = new OperationLog()
    operationLogInstance.properties = params
    operationLogInstance.validator = Validator.get(params.validatorId)
    operationLogInstance.operation = Operation.get(params.operationId)
    return [operationLogInstance: operationLogInstance]
}


def save = {
    def operationLogInstance = new OperationLog(params)
    println(params.validator)
    operationLogInstance.validator = Validator.get(params.validator.id);
    if (operationLogInstance.save(flush: true))
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'operationLog.label', default: 'OperationLog'), operationLogInstance.id])}"
}
```

If I select just one from select, it works perfectly but if I select two, I get the following exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.akent.Validator.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [3, 4]
Possible solutions: get(java.lang.Object), getId(), getIp(), getAt(java.lang.String), getAll(), ident()
```

Comment: You need validators to be a one-to-many relationship to support saving multiple validators in single OperationLog.

Comment: thank you for quick reply @ataylor but they are already in exact same relationship

**Validator.groovy:**
`static hasMany = [operationlog: OperationLog]`

**OperationLog.groovy:**
`static belongsTo = [Validator]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `MME` is because the `get()` on Domain classes only handles one id at a time.  For multiple ids from your `<select/>` use.

```
def validators = Validator.getAll(params.list('validator.id'))
```

The `params.list()` will always fetch 'validator.id' as a List even if there's only one, which will save you from having to test for single vs multiple results from your `<select/>`.

Comment: `def operationLogInstance = new OperationLog(params)`

**and I had to delete params in this line. Thank you @schmolly159**

Answer (score 1):

According to this docs: http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Tags/select.html your select tag is wrong, it should be rather:

```
<g:select name="validator.id"
    multiple="multiple"
    optionKey="id"
    from="${com.project.Validator.list()}"
    value="${contact?.validators*.id}" />
```