# DataBinding for multi select values

Tags: grails

If I have a domain object with one-to-many association and a corresponding edit view that uses 
`<g:select multiple="true" ...>` 
tag. How can I unassociate all the "many" objects?

In the controller I have the following line of code to update the object:

```
 objectInstance.properties = params
```

The problem is that if I unselect everything in the html form and submit it, the given property won't be included into the params. Since the property is not in `params`, the binding mechanism won't perform any update on this collection.

A simple fix would be to always check in the controller for pontentially cleared collections:

```
 if(!params.someCollection){
     params.someCollection = []
 }
 objectInstance.properties = params
```

In this case the data binding mechanism would clear the collection as desired.

But how to do it more generic? I don't want to do this check for every collection in every controller I already have.

I looked at the noSelection attribute in the g:select (I could perhaps live with a dedicated option which would be 'none') but it's not very usefull. First of all I would have to implement `require at least one` logic for this field and secondly noSelection default value would have to be handled somehow in the Controller (`-1` or `null` doesn't do the trick).

Answer (score -1):

To support mulit select binding :

But ,make sure that if select one value sent is String and if u select ,multiple value will be list of string or arraylist.

[For more see question here :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523887/grails-select-tag-results)

```
<g:select name="dhrsX.id" 
          from="${DeviceHistoryRecord.list()}"
          multiple="multiple"
          optionKey="id"
          value="${customerSiteInstance?.dhrs*.id}"/>
```